# RichTextBox text coloring has different behavior when added to the Form constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox  placed on a form and i want to add different text with different colors to it.
I used this [code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/richtextbox) to add color text to the RichTextBox, but it has a different behavior when i add it to the Form constructor( the first word is not colored).
can any one explain this different behavior?

Here's the code:

```
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 18f, FontStyle.Bold);
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        string[] words =
        {
        "Dot",
        "Net",
        "Perls",
        "is",
        "a",
        "nice",
        "website."
        };
        Color[] colors =
        {
        Color.Aqua,
        Color.CadetBlue,
        Color.Cornsilk,
        Color.Gold,
        Color.HotPink,
        Color.Lavender,
        Color.Moccasin
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
        string word = words[i];
        Color color = colors[i];
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = color;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(word);
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(" ");
        }
        }
```

Note: I use VS2010,.NET 3.5

Comment: I can't find the problem, they do each have a their own color in my solution ...(Do you mean the word "DOT"s' background isn't highlighted ?) BTW the curly braces before richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = color; and after richTextBox1.AppendText(" "); are unnecessary

Comment: @Lost Thanks for ur concern, yes i mean the "DOT"'s background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the reason is Control's `Handle` has not been created yet. It is created only when you first call to `AppendText`. though it shouldn't be a problem(I'll get back if I find why that's a problem).

To fix it, just force the creation of handle. You do this by requesting the `Handle` property.

```
var handle = richTextBox1.Handle;//Force create handle
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    string word = words[i];
    Color color = colors[i];

    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = color;
    richTextBox1.AppendText(word);
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    richTextBox1.AppendText(" ");

}
```

Comment: Do you mean adding this line before the code in the form constructor?

Comment: No, just see `var handle = richTextBox1.Handle;` before the loop. Add that line. It should work.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank u, it worked but i still don't know why did i got that behavior, shouldn't it create the handle once i initialized the components?

Comment: It is creating the `Handle` on first call to `AppendText`, me too wondering why this happens :(  I guess this is a bug..

Answer (score 1):

Move the code into the Load event and it will work:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorTbx();
    }

    private void colorTbx()
    {
        //your code here
    }
```